# How to download asus nexus 7 Android kitkat git for snapdragon processor

Tags: android, linux-kernel

I want to download android kitkat source code with kernel for asus nexus 7 for snapdragon processor. I tried searching in google but not getting exact repo to download.

Answer (score 1):

Here are [instructions on downloading and building kernels](https://source.android.com/source/building-kernels.html) for Nexus devices.

You need this one:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm.git
```

Comment: hi, what should be binary location while downloading android git for snapdragon processor. Actually asus nexus 7 using two versions 2012( for NVIDIA processor) and 2013( qualcomm snapdragon), i want to download source code for snapdragon processor so what should be the binary location for sanpdragon.

Comment: git clone https://android.googlesource.com/device/asus/flo-kernel.git -b android-4.4.4_r2.0.1

Comment: Hi, how to download android source code, the link which u have given is for kernel. Actually i was taking reference with the link  https://github.com/catalinionita/Ecryptfs-Tools-for-Android/wiki/Building-AOSP-4.4_r1.2-with-efs-tools-on-Nexus-7-Tablet    but this is for NVIDIA processor. In this they (told below AOSP source code) are using repo init and repo sync to download android source code, after syncing only they are downloading kernel. so i want to know how to sync that repo for sanpdragon.

Comment: @DeepakSingh Try this: https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html